# how to make a adjacency matrix in C++ for a surface

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, sparse-matrix, mesh

I am working on Graphite. Its is in C++ built-in libraries.

I am trying to make a surface which would be a sphere. The sphere is in form of a mesh.

How can I make adjacency matrix and degree matrix for a surface so that I can compute the Laplacian matrix?

I am working on a surface which I need to deform it later for that I need an adjacency matrix and degree matrix for the surface.

I am using C++.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't change the topology after the fact, a 2D array of points is enough, adjacency can remain implicit.

Answer (score 1):

**How to create adjacency matrix**

Here is how you can create an adjacency matrix:

```
#include <vector>

vector < vector<int> > adjacencyMatrix(vertices);
```

**How to derive degree matrix**

Consider the following adjacency matrix that represents an unweighted directed graph:

```
1 0 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

The index of the row represents the vertex.  So, row 0 represents vertex 0, 1 represents vertex 1...
The vertex 0 is connected to itself and has an incoming edge from vertex 2.  Similarly, 1 has an incoming edge from 0, and 2 has one with 1.

We have to find out how many edges end at each vertex.  Using that information, we create following degree matrix:

```
2 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

The above shows that vertex 0 has 2 edges ending on it, vertex 1 has 1, and vertex 2 has 1.

Since each row in the adjacency matrix represents the incoming connections for that vertex, all you have to do it sum up each row and store them in another matrix (i.e. degree matrix).  Since row 0 had a sum of 2, that means you store at the (0, 0) position of the degree matrix the value 2.  Similarly, since row 1 had a sum of 1, you store that value at the (1, 1) position...

Let me know if you need me to actually code this.  I'm assuming you understand and can take it from here.

Note: the above works for an adjacency matrix for unweighted directed graph. You will have to modify it slightly for other types of graphs.

Comment: Actually  I want to know how can i calculate the the adjacency matrix for a particular surface.

Comment: You are declaring it ...I know how to declare it .But I want to know the process of calculating not declaring the adjacency matrix. for a surface().

Comment: Yes, I understand. Give me a few minutes :)

Comment: Let me know if it makes any sense to you

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It seems to me more of a Degree matrix. As it shows the no. of connections or edges going from a particular vertex. Please refer to the link below as I think we are not on the same page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix

Comment: I see... so you want to create a Laplacian matrix from a Degree Matrix and Adjacency Matrix, is that correct?

Comment: Also, could clarify what type of graph trying to implement? Weighted or unweighted?  Directed or undirected?

Comment: Yes i wanted to create Laplacian matrix.....for uniform weights...in a directed graph..Like a sphere...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a undirected graph with N nodes, you need an NxN matrix (initialized to 0).

For each edge (a,b) in your graph mark the entry at (a,b) and (b,a) with 1 in the adjacency matrix, while the degree matrix is incremented with 1 at (a,a) and at (b,b).

For a simple graph (no multiple edges and self-loops) you have L = D - A.